# many-to-many relation in Room database. Kotlin Junction class ignored

Tags: android, kotlin, foreign-keys, android-room

I have the following Kotlin entities for Room ver. 2.2.5.

PARENT ENTITY

```
@Entity(tableName = "ITEM",
    indices = [Index(value = ["id"], unique = true), Index(value = ["code"], unique = true), Index(value = ["status"], unique = false)]
)
data class Item (
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "id") override val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
    @ColumnInfo(name = "code") @NotNull val code: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "valid") val valid: Boolean = true,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "value") val value: Double?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "price") val price: Double?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "default_description") val defaultDescription: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description") val description: String?
)
```

CHILD ENTITY

```
@Entity(tableName = "LOCATION",
    indices = [Index(value = ["id"], unique = true), Index(value = ["code"], unique = true)]
)
data class Location (
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id") @PrimaryKey override val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
    @ColumnInfo(name = "code") val code: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "latitude") val latitude: Double?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "longitude") val longitude: Double?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "default_description") val defaultDescription: String?
)
```

JUNCTION ENTITY

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "ITEM_LOCATION_L",
    primaryKeys = [
        "item_id", "location_id"
    ],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(entity = Item::class, parentColumns = ["id"], childColumns = ["item_id"]),
        ForeignKey(entity = Location::class, parentColumns = ["id"], childColumns = ["location_id"])
    ],
    indices = [
        Index("id"),
        Index("item_id"),
        Index("location_id")])
data class ItemLocationLink (
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id") override val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_id") val itemId: UUID, /** Item ID - parent entity */
    @ColumnInfo(name = "location_id") val locationId: UUID, /** Location ID - child entity */
    @ColumnInfo(name = "quantity") val quantity: Double /** Quantity of the item in the referenced location */
)
```

RESULT CLASS

```
class ItemLocationRelation {
    @Embedded
    lateinit var item: Item
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "id",
        associateBy = Junction(value = ItemLocationLink::class, parentColumn = "item_id", entityColumn = "location_id")
    ) lateinit var locations: List<Location>
}
```

DAO INTERFACE

```
@Dao
interface ItemLocationLinkDao {

   @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE id = :itemId")
    fun getLocationsForItem(itemId: UUID): List<ItemLocationRelation>
}
```

DATABASE TYPE CONVERTER

```
class DBTypesConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromUUID(uid: UUID?): String? {

        if (uid != null)
            return uid.toString()
        return null
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toUUID(str: String?): UUID? {

        if (str != null) {
            return UUID.fromString(str)
        }
        return null
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromDate(d: Date?): Long? {

        return d?.time
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toDate(l: Long?): Date? {

        return if (l != null) Date(l) else null
    }
}
```

When I call **getLocationsForItem** I get in return an instance of **ItemLocationRelation** with a valid Item but no child objects. I've checked the generated code and there is no sign of the Junction class. The generated code behaves like it is not a many-to-many relation, the Junction class is completely ignored, I can even specify a fake class in the @Junction attribute of the relation and the result would be exactly the same without errors.

If I add a function to the DAO class that returns the results of the following query:

```
select * from item 
inner join item_location_l as link on link.item_id = item.id
inner join LOCATION as l on link.location_id = l.id
where item.id = '99a3a64f-b0e6-e911-806a-68ecc5bcbe06'
```

I get 2 rows as expected. So the SQLite database is ok. Please help.

Comment: I don't see visible problems with your code (except that: 1. I didn't get what is overriding of some fields of your data classes about 2. It's not clear what a typeConverter for UUID have you used). I'm afraid that without full repo it would be a complicated task for somebody to help you

Comment: By the way, have you checked your query result manually? The simplest way - is to build query to all 3 tables with inner joins on  your item_id

Comment: Hi Sergiy, the type converter for UUID transform UUID into string and back. And it works fine. I also tried to replace UUID with long to no avail. I tried the query as you suggested to test and it works fine. The problem is that the generated code is completely missing the Junction table as it was just a one-to-many relationship. I've added the type converter in my question's code

Comment: So you say that in you generated DAO implementation class there is no table "ITEM_LOCATION_L" mentioning (search with the text)?

Comment: I debugged the code, there is no sign of the ITEM_LOCATION_L being used anywhere. I debugged the auto-generated code, it behaves like the relation is a one-to-one. I tried also to change the Junction in this way:  Junction(value = String::class, parentColumn = "item_id", entityColumn = "location_id"), forcing String as junction class. The code generated is exactly the same and I do not get any error. Exactly same result as before... the item is good but it has no child objects because the generated code searches using the item id instead of querying  ITEM_LOCATION_L for the right IDs

Comment: Is it your pet-project? Can you share the link to repository or make new with its simplified analogue?

Comment: Thank you very much Sergiy for your precious help, in the meantime I have discovered the problem. I'll write it in the answer... very tricky...

Answer (score 1):

So, in the end the problem was really subtle. For reasons I cannot explain the project I was working on had the following gradle settings (app gradle):

```
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:2.2.5"
```

**I replaced it with**

```
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"
```

And then everything was fine. The hard-coded query generated by the plugin now contains the JOIN and it works....